# Simple Operations Calculator

Tags: java, beginner, swing, error-handling, calculator

I'm practicing Swing effects. Everything works but for some reason I get a ton of error messages in the command prompt when the fields are empty, despite my attempt to add some exception handling (this has made me realize I need to practice that a lot more).

```
    /* Author: Luigi Vincent
Practicing Java Swing button and button events; Window that does simple calculation on two numbers
TO DO: Figure out why command prompt show so many messages when fields are empty & stop it
*/

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class SimpleCalc extends JFrame {

    SimpleCalc (String name) {
        super(name);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Fields for input and output
        JTextField result = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField num1 = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField num2 = new JTextField(5);
        result.setEditable(false);

        // Buttons for operations
        JButton b_add = new JButton("Add");
        JButton b_sub = new JButton("Subtract");
        JButton b_mul = new JButton("Multiply");
        JButton b_div = new JButton("Divide");

        // Listener to handle operations
        ActionListener calculator = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    if (num1.getText().length() == 0 || num2.getText().length() == 0) {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Field missing", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }

                Double alpha = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText());
                Double beta = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText());
                Double omega = null;
                DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");

                if (e.getSource() == b_add) {
                    omega = alpha + beta;
                }
                else if (e.getSource() == b_sub) {
                    omega = alpha - beta;
                }
                else if (e.getSource() == b_mul) {
                    omega = alpha * beta;
                }
                else if (e.getSource() == b_div) {
                    omega = alpha / beta;
                }
                result.setText(f.format(omega).toString());
            }
        };
       // Register buttons to event listener
        b_add.addActionListener(calculator);
        b_sub.addActionListener(calculator);
        b_mul.addActionListener(calculator);
        b_div.addActionListener(calculator);

       // Add everything to frame + labels    
        add(new JLabel("First Number"));
        add(num1);
        add(new JLabel("Second Number"));
        add(num2);
        add(new JLabel("Result"));
        add(result);
        add(b_add);
        add(b_sub);
        add(b_mul);
        add(b_div);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleCalc frame = new SimpleCalc("Simple Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 100);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm open to any and all improvements possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major problem I can see is this piece of code :

> ```
>             try {
>                 if (num1.getText().length() == 0 || num2.getText().length() == 0) {
>                     throw new Exception();
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex){
>                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Field missing", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
>             }
> ```

If you `throw` inside a `try-catch`, you will not exit the function. Since your condition is `num1.getText().length() == 0` when you try to do `Double.parseDouble(num1.getTest()` well your string is empty so this throw an exception.

You should not use `throw` and `catch` to manage an error, not in this way. You should first remove the `try-catch` and work with a simple `if` :

```
if (num1.getText().isEmpty() || num2.getText().isEmpty()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Field missing", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

I would not suggested that since now you add a complexity to your code.

- The method now need to declare `throws Exception` (which is not possible for `actionPerformed()`), now the caller need to manage this possible outcome.
- `Exception` would be too generic.
- I guess that this case would happen a lot,so throwing an `Exception` could become heavy for the program.

The real solution is to only `return` from the method. You've already warned the user that he need to do something (you could be more clear) and you don't want to execute the rest of method.

---

There is some general notion that are lacking in your code, but I won't cover it all, since I mention it in others answer :

- There is naming convetions in Java, `b_add` does not follow it, it should be `bAdd` (but it could simply be `add`)
- You should not extend `JFrame`, but rather just have a `private JFrame`, you're not adding any functionnality to `JFrame` you're only using it. (Composition over inheritance) [answer that cover a bit that part](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54738)

Comment: Mind at least tell me which of those 'other answers' I should look at? Thank you for the input, it was very helpful! I think I was forcing myself to use an Exception when it wasn't necessary, and the parse.double completely eluded me. Quick question about composition over inheritance, if I did it the plain way wouldn't all of this have to be in the main method? (I read somewhere around here that that was bad practice...)

Comment: No, not at all. You will have a field `private JFrame mainFrame;` and your constructor will still take a `String`. You will then make a `new JFrame(name)` and change all your `setLayout` and `add` (in fact all the JFrame call) like this `mainFrame.setLayout("")`. For another answer to look read this one about generic style : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55904

Comment: Did you need more explanation about he double part or you were good ? And I didn't linked specific answers to not "advertise" myself too much! There are plenty of good answers here that will help you about the generic stuff of Jave! I would recommend you to browse the java and swing tag for more information (reading code can help a lot!)